# ios_base::sync_with_stdio optimization

Tags: c++

`ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` makes `std::cout` & `std::cin` faster wouldn't be the best code when you turn it on and off depending on your needs of `printf`
example:

```
.....

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)

std::cin << num;

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(true);

printf("%d", num);
```

or does the command `ios_base::sync_with_stdio` even make the code slower ?
just enabling and disabling it on your needs
please help

Comment: I have yet to see a real-life production worthy program where turning `sync_with_stdio` off made any meaningful difference. But, I *have* seen it cause problems. Just leave it alone. Real programs don't write to standard streams often enough to be anything to care about. Move on, solve *real* problems instead.

Comment: Okey thanks, I am comming from the C language thats why I ask , thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The function `sync_with_stdio()` has no effect after you have written to or read from a stream.  Try to consider how it would even be possible to do so, once the input has been consumed or the output flushed.